# What is the statement "If not p then q" called?

Tags: logic, terminology

Let's say I have a statement: if p then q.
The converse would be: if q then p.
The inverse would be: if not p then not q.
The contraposition would be: if not q then not p.
What would you call the following? if not p then q.
Thanks.

Comment: negation of converse?

Comment: I don't think it has a name.

Comment: @hjpotter92 can you show it to us how it's called negation of converse?

Comment: @Rustyn One reaason I could think of why I would not call it "p or q" is when the statement "p implies q" has a name, e.g. the "p or q" of principle x

Answer (score 3):

$$
p \Rightarrow q \equiv \lnot p \lor q  $$

$$
\lnot p \Rightarrow q \equiv p\lor q 
$$
It is logically equivalent to "$p$ or $q$"

Comment: That's not really a name for it so much as a statement that happens to be equivalent to it in classical logic.  I don't think the equivalence holds intuitionistically, so it probably wouldn't be good to call the one a "name" for the other.

Comment: @TrevorWilson can you expound what you mean by intuitionistically?

Comment: @bimboxX I mean that, assuming $\neg p \implies q$, it seems like one might need to use the law of excluded middle ($p \vee \neg p$) to conclude $p \vee q$.

Comment: Ah, so it's like you have to "cross a bridge" to get to "p or q". But the two statements are still equal, right? I'm just thinking if there's a name for "p or q" in relation to "not p implies q" then I could gladly use it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no name for it, because there's no real connection between them. The inverse and converse exist because they still assert a direct correlation between p and q; it's just that, as opposed to the regular and contrapositive forms, the condition for failure is reversed.

On the other hand, "if not p then q" is a completely different assertion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "correlation" here.  For any definition I can think of, if $p$ and $q$ are correlated then so are $\neg p$ and $q$.

Comment: There is no reason why $\lnot p$ and $q$ must be correlated if $p$ and $q$ are correlated. All four of the related forms (regular, contrapositive, converse, and inverse) state that $p$ and $q$ should be true simultaneously under some specific condition. There is no inherent correlation between $\lnot p$ and $q$, because $\lnot p$ does not imply, or even suggest, anything about $q$ when $p$ implies $q$.

Comment: @GlenO can you cite a specific condition for example?

Comment: This is what I'm saying: in the truth tables for the regular, contrapositive, converse, and inverse, if both p and q are true, then the statement is true. Similarly, if both p and q are false, then the statement is true. On the other hand, with "if not p then q", if both p and q are true, the statement is false.

Comment: So, "if it is hot, then I'm sweating" is the regular statement. A reasonable statement. "If I'm not sweating, then it is not hot" is also a reasonable statement, the contrapositive. "If it is not hot, then I'm not sweating" is a statement with less accuracy, as it is possible for me to be sweating when it's not hot, and similarly for "if I'm sweating, then it is hot" - but they're mostly consistent with the original observation that heat and sweating are related. But "if it is not hot, then I'm sweating" is a completely different statement.

Comment: I'll check that one out.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still wondering what you mean by "correlated".  If we use it in the statistical sense, if the truth values of $p$ and $q$ are correlated, then so are the truth values of $\neg p$ and $q$, right?

Comment: When I say "correlated", I'm not including negative correlation, as per statistics, but only positive correlation, matching the lay use of the term. One would not assert (in lay terms) that sweating is correlated to coldness.

Comment: Oh, I see!  Sometimes I forget how lay people use our words :-)

Comment: As checked, if both p and q are true, then the statement "not p implies q" can be true too. Please correct me if I'm wrong, "if it's not hot, then I'm sweating" is also a statement with less accuracy because we can also be hinted (just like in inverse) that "if it's hot then I'm not sweating".

Comment: Oops, I misspoke, @bimboxX - it's the "p and q are both false" case that changes. As for the accuracy thing - "if it's not hot then I'm sweating" is a completely different assertion from "if it's hot then I'm sweating". The only explicit assertion being made in that case is the complete opposite of the assertion being made by the regular statement, associating sweating with the opposite circumstance.

Comment: Hmm.. if that's the case then can I call it the opposite circumstance implication of p on q? :D